# fig.savefig Exporting as Blank

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This code ultimately outputs an all white .png file.  The image renders properly in Jupyter Notebooks. What am I doing wrong?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[70, 70])

size = 1
ax.set_title('Groups, 2019 vs 2020')

colours = ['red', 'darkorange', 'lawngreen', 'dodgerblue', 'mediumpurple', 'deeppink']
labels = ['tv film', 'comms', 'health', 'ent other', 'elections', 'misc']
data = [tv_film_mean_2020, comms_mean_2020, 
        health_mean_2020, ent_other_mean_2020, 
        elections_mean_2020, misc_mean_2020]
ax.pie(x = data, radius=4,labels=labels, labeldistance=.9, pctdistance=.85,colors=colours, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='black'), autopct='%1.1f%%')


sub_colours = ['red', 'darkorange', 'lawngreen', 'dodgerblue', 'mediumpurple', 'deeppink']
sub_labels = ['tv film(2019)', 'comms(2019)', 'health(2019)', 
              'ent other(2019)', 'elections(2019)', 'misc(2019)']

sub_data = [tv_film_mean_2019, comms_mean_2019, 
            health_mean_2019, ent_other_mean_2019, 
            elections_mean_2019, misc_mean_2019]

ax.pie(x = sub_data, radius=(3), pctdistance=.72,labels=sub_labels, labeldistance=0.8, colors=sub_colours, rotatelabels=True, wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='black'), autopct='%1.1f%%')

ax.set(aspect="equal")

fig.savefig(f'../output_graphs/Group_Nested_agg.png',bbox_inches='tight',transparent = False,dpi=100)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you 2nd line reassigns the variable `fig` to a new plot that does not have `ax` on it (which you then add all your data to). I don't think you need or want the line:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[70, 70])
```

You should be able to add the `figsize=[70, 70]` to the first line, e.g.:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[70, 70])
```